# Formatting USB flash drive securely on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, security, usb-drive

After days of searching on the internet - I really need you help.

I have fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04. No additional software has been installed. Also no changes to the system have been made. It is really just clean installation from DVD and update through “software update”.

I want to connect an USB-drive to this system and format it. I do not need to open any files from USB-drive. The only purpose is to have a fat32 formatted USB-drive.

How to perform this action without risking to get a worm or any other malware potentially contained on the USB-drive?

Answer (score 1):

General advice:

- You can use the built-in tool **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` to format the USB-drive.
- or you can [install **mkusb** from its PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and use it either

  - to format the USB-drive (create a fresh partition table with one FAT32 partition) that you ask for
  - or a more advanced 2 step procedure to first wipe the whole device (overwrite with zeros) and then format it.

Please ask in a comment, if you need more details.

Comment: thank you sododus for the answer. I was thinking to use the build-in Disks tool. The question is if any malware can gain access to my PC from just attaching the drive to it and then opening Disks utility (since disk utility is somehow accessing the USB-drive).

Comment: Most malware cannot attack Ubuntu. Some malware attack only when you open a file with some tool, for example word processor. But I have heard of malware that resides in the internal system of the USB drive itself. I don't know anybody who has been hit by such malware, but it might be able to attack any computer, including computers with Linux (and Ubuntu is a Linux distro). So I cannot give a 100% guarantee, but I can say that I would use both Disks and mkusb without fear to format any random USB-drive.

Comment: Another way to answer: If you need military level of security, never connect your computer to the internet, and never connect any USB devices to it. If you need normal high security for private purposes, you can connect to the internet and you can use USB drives, but avoid obvious risks. Example: you can have a second 'test' computer to perform risky tasks.